# IE 10/11: Image preview from API response

Tags: reactjs, internet-explorer, blob

I can see the image returned in the API response, but unable to set it as the src of an img element in my page in IE 10/11.
In Chrome, this ReactJS code works fine:

```
return fetch(url, sInit)
      .then(response => response.blob())
      .then((blobResponse) => {
        let fileUrl = (window.URL || window.webkitURL).createObjectURL(blobResponse);
        // setting fileUrl as src for <img>
      });
```

This fileUrl is then set as the src attribute of an img element.

But I need a solution for IE 10/11 so that image can be previewed in the designated position.

Note: The workaround of `window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob` is not what I need.

Comment: Are you using a polyfill for `fetch()` in IE10/11? (as `fetch()` is [not supported in IE10/11](https://caniuse.com/#search=fetch)).

Comment: yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to accomplish in this below way:

```
return fetch(url, sInit)
  .then(response => response.blob())
  .then((blobResponse) => {
    if (window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) { // Checking if IE
      let reader = new FileReader();
      let dataURL = '';
      reader.onload = function readerFile(e) {
        dataURL = reader.result;
        // setting dataURL as src for <img>
      };
      reader.readAsDataURL(blobResponse);
    } else {
      let fileUrl = (window.URL || window.webkitURL).createObjectURL(blobResponse);
      // setting fileUrl as src for <img>
    }
  });
```